Regroup elements in data frame based on pair information
Say I have a data frame like the following:
mydf <- data.frame(id=LETTERS, locus=c(rep("alpha",14),rep("beta",12)),
                   group=c(rep(1,2),rep(2,6),rep(3,6),rep(4,4),rep(5,4),rep(6,4)),
                   pair=c(1:12,14,15,3,4,6,8,9:16))

which looks like this:
> mydf
   id locus group pair
1   A alpha     1    1
2   B alpha     1    2
3   C alpha     2    3
4   D alpha     2    4
5   E alpha     2    5
6   F alpha     2    6
7   G alpha     2    7
8   H alpha     2    8
9   I alpha     3    9
10  J alpha     3   10
11  K alpha     3   11
12  L alpha     3   12
13  M alpha     3   14
14  N alpha     3   15
15  O  beta     4    3
16  P  beta     4    4
17  Q  beta     4    6
18  R  beta     4    8
19  S  beta     5    9
20  T  beta     5   10
21  U  beta     5   11
22  V  beta     5   12
23  W  beta     6   13
24  X  beta     6   14
25  Y  beta     6   15
26  Z  beta     6   16

It has an id column as a primary key, and ids are divided into locus alpha and beta. Each id in alpha should have a pair in beta (column pair), though there might be cases of orphan alpha or beta ids (due to prior filtering).
ids are also grouped in different groups (column group), which were defined on a per-locus basis.
Now I want to define another grouping variable new_group that reflects the alpha-beta pairing information.
This seems very straightforward visually, but I am struggling to define the rules in an automatic way, so that every possible situation is taken into account.
The desired output for the example data frame above would be the following (colors just for guidance):

Note that I only define a new_group when pair information is found, so ids A and B do not belong to any new_group.
ids C, D, F and H have pair information in beta, so they all constitute new_group 1; since ids E and G belong to the same group, they are pooled together (even if they do not have pair information).
ids from I to N have pair information in beta grouped in different groups, so new_group 2 has to be split in beta into 2a and 2b.
Essentially, rules would be:

make a new group when at least one id of a group contains pair info in the other locus
for ids without pair info, pool them into the same new group if other ids from their group have paired info
groups in alpha can be paired to multiple groups in beta, and conversely groups in beta can be paired to multiple groups in alpha, in which case letter suffixes are used


Here is an igraph solution
mbs <- mydf %>%
  mutate(sg = str_c("g", group), sp = str_c("p", pair)) %>%
  select(sg, sp) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  components() %>%
  membership()

mydf %>%
  mutate(new_group = mbs[startsWith(names(mbs), "g")][str_c("g", group)]) %>%
  mutate(
    new_group = ifelse(n_distinct(locus) == 2, new_group - 1, NA),
    .by = new_group
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    new_group = if (n_distinct(group) == 1) as.character(new_group) else str_c(new_group, "_",match(group, unique(group))),
    .by = c(locus, new_group)
  )

which gives
   id locus group pair new_group
1   A alpha     1    1      <NA>
2   B alpha     1    2      <NA>
3   C alpha     2    3         1
4   D alpha     2    4         1
5   E alpha     2    5         1
6   F alpha     2    6         1
7   G alpha     2    7         1
8   H alpha     2    8         1
9   I alpha     3    9         2
10  J alpha     3   10         2
11  K alpha     3   11         2
12  L alpha     3   12         2
13  M alpha     3   14         2
14  N alpha     3   15         2
15  O  beta     4    3         1
16  P  beta     4    4         1
17  Q  beta     4    6         1
18  R  beta     4    8         1
19  S  beta     5    9       2_1
20  T  beta     5   10       2_1
21  U  beta     5   11       2_1
22  V  beta     5   12       2_1
23  W  beta     6   13       2_2
24  X  beta     6   14       2_2
25  Y  beta     6   15       2_2
26  Z  beta     6   16       2_2


Great answer! But what happens when you run out of letters?

@Edward haha, that's an interesting situation :) I guess digital suffix for sub-groups should be a better option in that case.

This is exactly what I was looking for! Great answer. I don't expect more than 3 subgroups in any case, so letter suffix is more than enough for my case. Many thanks!!

You can also visualise the clusters using the igraph package.

The colours of the edges come from the locus (amber="alpha", blue="beta").

R Code:
mbs <- mydf %>%
  mutate(sg = paste0("g", group), sp = paste0("p", pair)) %>%
  select(sg, sp, locus) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) # Modified slightly from Thomas' answer

ceb <- cluster_edge_betweenness(ig)

plot(ceb, ig, 
     col="yellow", # vertex colour
     edge.color = as.factor(E(ig)$locus), edge.width=3)



The visualisation looks gorgeous, +1!

Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. Alas, I couldn’t understand why p14 and p15 were grouped with g6 (magenta, or the beta locus) and not g3 (cyan, or the alpha locus). If so, then I think this would be nice way to identify the desired ‘new_group’ groups.

The community detection is based on the edge-betweenness score, I have no exact clue why p14 and p15 don't belong to g3 group. So far I cannot find obvious evidence that how strong the OP's request is relevant to edge betweenness, but there maybe something interesting related under the hood.

This really does help a lot, thanks!
